# DeviceOrientationControls.js - Calibration to ideal starting center

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using an equirectangular video as a texture for a sphere. You can mouse pan around the environment, but on mobile, I'd like to use this solution: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js

It works great, however, I'm not sure how to "calibrate" or "orient" on start to an ideal center. Because the video starts with a logo in the dead center of the video, the user must move the device around to find where that is. On start, I'd like to orient the sphere or camera so that the "center" of what the user sees is the ideal center to start from. I suppose it's initial calibration around the Y-axis?

I apologize, I'm not super familiar with terms to use. Please let me know if I can help clarify. I most certainly fundamental gaps in my understanding.

I had a little success grabbing the initial alpha and using that as an offset during up, but orientation changes affect this negatively.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: Here is a crude drawing. Updated 3.14.2015.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9imI.jpg

Based on the comment from @WestLangley, I could rotate the mesh. This would work well, but I need to be able to rotate the mesh based on an initial offset to ensure the orb is initially rotated to the 'same' spot at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `DeviceOrientationControls`, and viewing a texture on the inner surface of a sphere mesh.

If you want to apply an initial rotation to the texture on the sphere, you can use this pattern:

```
mesh.material.map.wrapS = mesh.material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
mesh.material.map.offset.set( 0.25, 0 ); // quarter-turn
```

Alternatively, in your case, you can rotate the sphere, instead:

```
mesh.rotation.set( 0, Math.PI / 2, 0 );
```

three.js r.70

Comment: Thank you @WestLangley. What I'm struggling with is how to orient the mesh to a natural center so that the mesh is rotated to the same starting location, regardless of where the user is initially looking.

I suppose I would describe it as an initial mesh rotation offset. I'm editing the original question with a crude drawing.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I tried the latter. Unfortunately, though this rotates the mesh, the problem still exists in that the mesh is always oriented the same way (even with an initial, fixed rotation offset). Basically, the mesh should rotate to an offset at the start regardless of where the user is facing when they initially start to look. I've updated my [crude drawing](http://i.imgur.com/Mds036U.jpg) :) What I'm struggling with is how to formulate that dynamic rotation offset.

Comment: With my iPhone, I get your desired behavior using either of my suggested methods.

Comment: I may have a misunderstanding as to how this should work. The mesh should rotate based where the user initially looks. This might be north, west, etc. As I understand this solution, the mesh is simply being rotated by a fixed offset. If for example there was a logo that always displayed when looking north, now I might only see this logo looking west. The mesh isn't calibrated to where the user initially starts to look.

Comment: With this solution, if you start the test case looking west and then restart it, but you are looking east, the mesh is rotated so that you see the same thing at the start? On a Note 4, the mesh was rotated, but the problem still remains. The user would need to know where to point the device to see the intended starting content. Because we don't know what direction the user will start looking, the solution is that we initially orient (dynamic rotation offset should work) the orb to where they should initially be looking at. I wonder if a rotation offset based on initial alpha, beta, gamma?

Comment: Yep! It was my misunderstanding. I applied the transform only once. Now I'm passing the mesh and applying the rotation as part of the setObjectQuaternion return function. Now it's working a charm. Thank you eternally for your help!